# accessible css dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

I have a problem with a pure css accessible dropdown menu, I'm tryng to navigate within the keyboard,  I mean tab button, but the second level doesn't focus, here is a sample: http://advidea.com/test/menu.html,

Answer (score 3):

I think this is similar to the one you're trying to achieve. I'll take a better look at your code and try to see if I can correct it.

By now, stay with this one: http://jsfiddle.net/cfWpE/

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox 15 (for Ubuntu).

Comment: When using the keyboard to navigate, the submenu items get invisible.