# CSS: How does setting a right margin cause the element's parent to become visible in this example?

Tags: html, css

While looking for keyboard-accessible menus, I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741521/accessible-css-dropdown-menu), which has as its answer a CSS drop-down menu http://jsfiddle.net/cfWpE/.  It seems to use styling on the anchors in the menu rather than `:hover` on the `<ul>` items to display the submenus without any Javascript, but I can't figure out how.

Could someone who's better than me at CSS explain how this works?  I'd like to try to extend this to a 3-level menu, but without understanding how it works for two levels, that's going to be difficult.

**edited for clarity:**

It's not actually the keyboard part that confuses me; I understand that tabbing through updates `:focus` on the current focus link, but the only CSS rule that seems to be applied to those elements is

```
ul.menu li.list a.category:hover,
ul.menu li.list a.category:focus,
ul.menu li.list a.category:active {
    margin-right:1px;
    background: black;
}
```

I don't understand how setting margin-right to 1 pixel makes the parent `<li>` visible.

Comment: Check out the rules using `:focus` (along with `:hover` and `:active`), which allows for keyboard interaction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an interesting Technique to achieve a dropdown menu.

The list items `.list` have a very high negative `margin-top` and a width of `250px`. This places their content out of the viewport of the browser. The child anchors `a.category` have a positive margin-top with exact the same value, so they are visible to the user as if they were positioned normally. Now both, the `a.category` and the `ul.submenu` have a `float:left` applied. that's why the submenu does not appear beneath the anchor, but beside it. (But it has no margin-top, so it is still "invisible") Both elements (`a.category` and `ul.submenu`) have `125px` width and fit perfectly into the parent `li` which has a width of `250px`. Now on hover the anchor gets an additional `1px` margin. This makes both elements too wide to fit into the parent container side to side and so the floated submenu breaks onto a newline and suddenly appears below the anchor - TADA:-D

I hope you could follow my explanation - if not ask please which part I need to clarify;)

Extending this to a third level is not possible - I would just go with a regular css-menu with `display:block;` and `hide`. However, you can use absolute positioning and switch the `top` value from a very high negative value to `0` when hovering, which would have the same effect.

<sub>Generally, i would use this with care. Some searchengines consider text that is hidden via negative margins or text-indent as [blackhat SEO](http://websearch.about.com/od/seononos/a/spamseo.htm) and may penalize one for that. Although it might be possible that Google is clever enough to recognize this as a regular dropdown-menu</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  I asked a couple other people, and no one could figure it out either.