# accessibility menu - open menu on focus

Tags: css, accessibility

in my site i have menu and sub menu

my problem when i focus by tab to the menu, the menu opened like i hovered the menu by mouse.
but when i continued to the sub menu elements with tab the menu closed.

how can i keep the menu open if some of sub element is focused.

of course i can do it via javascript, but i want to know if i can do it with css only.

here is example (try go to links with 'tab' )

```css
li.main{
  
  float:left;
  width:200px;
}
li .sub{
  display:none;
  }
li:hover .sub{
  display:block
    }

li.main:focus .sub{
   display:block
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="main"  tabindex="0">
    First menu
    <div class='sub'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First Link</a> </li>
         <li><a href="#">Second Link</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li> <li class="main"  tabindex="0">
    Second menu
    <div class='sub'>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Third Link</a> </li>
         <li><a href="#">Forth Link</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: What you're looking for there are parent selectors which, unfortunately, don't exist yet so, for now, JavaScript is the route you'll need to go.

Answer (score 0):

**With the current possibilities of CSS, you can't**, as it was discussed in a lot of questions before (see [accessible css dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741521/accessible-css-dropdown-menu) for instance).

First of all, you can't use "display:none" in such approach because the link can't be accessed using the next link shortcut (tab key in most of the browsers implementation).

Solutions which work will imply solutions like positioning out of screen. It will restrict the view on screen to the current link as there is no parent() selector in CSS, or you might use a trick like in the above thread (which will work in some browsers and limit the width of the dropdown part).

But no matter the solution, it will not resolve the main problem : **a dropdown menu is not the best way to achieve accessibility**.

**For instance, people with disabilities using eye tracking software will never benefit of a dropdown menu. Neither will people using tablet.**

It is always something difficult to use, difficult to understand : What if I click on the category link? Does it open the category main page, or does it open the submenu?

**If you really want an accessible menu, do not use a dropdown menu**